# Cannot find name 'Promise' in visual studio code

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I am using Angular2 with Visual studio code. In visual studio code It shows me error as shown below :

[image]

As seen in the image `Promise` is highlighted with red underline. Also I have another query is if we define inline function then Visual studio code will also shows red underline below the name of function. Like `response` is shown with red underline in above image.

However my code works fine in browser. but in VS Code it shows me red underline.

I don't want any red underline in my code. Is it possible ? Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Your URL, isn't really hidden in the image

Comment: have a look at this answer by theirry templier : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618012/why-do-i-get-the-error-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observablerespon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the visual studio has functionality for visible intellisense for any language, you can just add the ***typings.json*** file in root level and add below code to it.

-- your typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459"
  }
}
```

and just hit the below command in cmd to current working project directory (install typings globally(-g) if not installed on your machine).

**typings install**

So only in visual studio, you will get the intellisense and remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install the typings of `es6-shim`.

First install typings with:

`npm install typings --global`

Install the `es6-shim` typings with:

`typings install es6-shim --save`

You should have a typings folder now, with `es6-shim.d.ts`.

If you don't have a `jsconfig.json` file you will need to reference those typings by placing this on the top of your file:

`/// <reference path='./path/to/typings' />`

Comment: I have already installed both `typings` and `es6-shim` but still VS Code shows me red underline. HOWEVER my application works smoothly.  I think something is not configured properly in VS code.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja did you add the reference path?

Comment: I am using typescript so, added reference to tsconfig.json file like this : http://prntscr.com/bdaji2. But still i am not getting intallisense and VS code showing red underline. shown as in my question.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja have you tried adding `/// <reference path="/typings">` to the file where you need promises? instead of the tsconfig?

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja is your typings folder in the root or inside node_modules?

Comment: Thanks for you efforts. I had installed through npm so, it is inside node_modules. Also i given correct path in reference tag. But still not working

Comment: Have you used `Promise` with using VS code ? If yes then in your VS code aren't showing red underline below `Promise`?

Comment: Yes. I am using Promise and its fine.

Comment: In my case application is working fine but red underline shown in VS code as you can see in image. I want to remove that

Comment: To remove that I did those steps and it worked fine. Not sure where your problem may be.