# Why do I get the error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'"?

Tags: typescript, angular

This is for an angular2 project with typescript running on Intellij15. I have imported 'rxjs/add/operator/map', but I still get the above error.
This is my code. I have checked other similar questions on SO, but have not found a solution.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: "h-recommend",
    template:`
    <div>
        hi
    </div>
    `
})

export class Recommendations implements OnInit{

    constructor (private _http: Http){}

    ngOnInit():any {

        this._http.get('../jsonfile/guestRecommendations/1.json')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.hello();
                alert(data);
            });
    }

     hello(){
        alert("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it an error during compilation or at execution time?

Comment: It happens at compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it happens at compilation, I guess that you don't have the typings for es6-shim / core-js.

You need this in your `typings.json` file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
     "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654", // <-------
     "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
     "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

You can install these typings using the `typings install` command.

See this page for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: The above solution solved my current problem. Now I get new compiler errors. Error:(85, 23) TS1110: Type expected and Error:(1917, 52) TS1005: '=' expected...Not sure what the solution for this is (newbie with typescript).

Comment: It occurs in the file .../browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts

Comment: I'm having the same problem. importing rxjs/add/operator/map and everything but still getting the error about map not exist. there is no typings, when i google what it is, i get a page that says deprecated.